# How do I assign the output of a `str.contains` to a Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

This must have been answered somewhere else, but I can't find the link. I have a `df` with some arbitrary text and a list of words `W`. I would like to assign a new column to `df` such that it contains the word in `W` that it matched. For example, given the `df`

```
   T
   dog
   dog and meerkat
   cat
```

and if W="dog", then I would like to have

```
   T
   dog                dog
   dog and meerkat    dog
   cat
```

What I have so far is

```
df[df.T.str.contains('|'.join(W), case=False)]
```

but that only gives me the rows that match,  that is:

```
   T
   dog
   dog and meerkat
```

Any ideas, pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) - where is not match get `NaN`:

```
W = 'dog'
df['new'] = df['T'].where(df['T'].str.contains('|'.join(W), case=False))
print (df)
                 T              new
0              dog              dog
1  dog and meerkat  dog and meerkat
2              cat              NaN
```

Or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
W = 'dog'
df.loc[df['T'].str.contains('|'.join(W), case=False), 'new'] = df['T']
print (df)
                 T              new
0              dog              dog
1  dog and meerkat  dog and meerkat
2              cat              NaN
```

Another possible solution is [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) where is possible add value if no match:

```
W = 'dog'
df['new'] = np.where(df['T'].str.contains('|'.join(W), case=False), df['T'], 'nothing')
print (df)
                 T              new
0              dog              dog
1  dog and meerkat  dog and meerkat
2              cat          nothing
```

---

But if need only matched value of list use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and for `groups` add first and last `()`:

```
W = ['dog', 'rabbit']
df['new'] = df['T'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(W) + ')', expand=True)
print (df)
                 T  new
0              dog  dog
1  dog and meerkat  dog
2              cat  NaN
```

[Extracting in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings).

Comment: wow. Impressive speed there :) but I actually need only the matched word, "dog" in this case, rather than the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking outside the box

***boolean array dot product with array of words***

```
df['T'].str.contains('dog')[:, None].dot(pd.Index(['dog']))
```

---

```
df.assign(new=df['T'].str.contains('dog')[:, None].dot(pd.Index(['dog'])))

                    T  new
0                 dog  dog
1     dog and meerkat  dog
2                 cat
```